# How can I load test a third-party JavaScript to estimate load times for users?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jmeter, apachebench

I'd like to add a third-party JavaScript to my site, but I'm concerned about negatively impacting user experience. I place something like this just above `</body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://third-party.com/script.js"></script>
```

The referenced script is just a few lines that passes 3 key-value pairs (including  a cookie) in `json`.

Before including this script I'd like to test how fast it will return at scale.

How can I verify the third-party server can handle (let's say) 1000 concurrent connections? And how can I measure average latency and run time?

I tried just referencing the remote JavaScript via an HTTP_REQUEST on Apache JMeter, but it doesn't actually run the script, it just loads the file. That helps with estimating latency but not script run time.

Comment: Is async loading of the script an option? That would be an easy way to prevent load time issues.

Comment: Yes `async` is an option in `<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://third-party.com/script.js"></script>`

Comment: _"How can I verify the third-party server can handle (let's say) 1000 concurrent connections? And how can I measure average latency and run time?"_ You can't unless they reveal details about their infrastructure (or you 'test' it for them). Even then you can only make guesses. I suggest you contact the third-party and ask them. Failing that you should find the library on a CDN.